# get the latest aws volume snapshot-id using python3 and boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am new to `python` and `boto3`, I want to get the latest snapshot ID.

I am not sure if I wrote the sort with lambda correctly and how to access the last snapshot, or maybe I can do it with the first part of the script when I print the `snapshot_id` and `snapshot_date` ?

Thanks.

Here is my script

```
import boto3
ec2client = mysession.client('ec2', region_name=region)
ec2resource = mysession.resource('ec2', region_name=region)

def find_snapshots():
    for snapshot in ec2client_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']:
        snapshot_volume = snapshot['VolumeId']
        mnt_vol = "vol-xxxxx"
        if mnt_vol == snapshot_volume:
            snapshot_date = snapshot['StartTime']
            snapshot_id = snapshot['SnapshotId']
            print(snapshot_id)
            print(snapshot_date)

find_snapshots()

snapshots = ec2resource.snapshots.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'volume-id', 'Values': [mnt_vol]}]).all()
print(snapshots)
snapshots = sorted(snapshots, key=lambda ss:ss.start_time)
print(snapshots)
snapshot_ids = map(lambda ss:ss.id, snapshots)
print(snapshot_ids)

last_snap_id = ?
```

output:

```
snap-05a8e27b15161d3d5
2016-12-25 05:00:17+00:00
snap-0b87285592e21f0
2016-12-25 03:00:17+00:00
snap-06fa39b86961ffa89
2016-12-24 03:00:17+00:00

ec2.snapshotsCollection(ec2.ServiceResource(), ec2.Snapshot)
[]
<map object at 0x7f8d91ea9cc0>
```

*update question to @roshan answer:

```
def find_snapshots():
    list_of_snaps = []
    for snapshot in ec2client_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']:
        snapshot_volume = snapshot['VolumeId']
        if mnt_vol == snapshot_volume:
            snapshot_date = snapshot['StartTime']
            snapshot_id = snapshot['SnapshotId']
            list_of_snaps.append({'date':snapshot['StartTime'], 'snap_id': snapshot['SnapshotId']})
    return(list_of_snaps)

find_snapshots()

print(find_snapshots())

#sort snapshots order by date
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])  
print(newlist)
```

output:

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 25, 14, 23, 37, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'snap_id': 'snap-0de26a40c1d1e53'}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 24, 22, 9, 34, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'snap_id': 'snap-0f0341c53f47a08'}]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 115, in <module>
    newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])  
NameError: name 'list_to_be_sorted' is not defined
```

If I do:

```
list_to_be_sorted = (find_snapshots())
print(list_to_be_sorted)
#sort snapshots order by date
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['snap_id'])
print(newlist[0])
```

the latest snapshot does not appear in the output:

```
{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 3, 0, 18, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'snap_id': 'snap-0225cff1675c369'}
```

this one is the latest:

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 25, 5, 0, 17, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'snap_id': 'snap-05a8e27b15161d5'}
```

How do I get the latest snapshot (`snap_id`) ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking and sample code does not work.

Comment: its working, I want to find all the snapshots with specific volume, and get the latest snapshot of that volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should it sort in `reverse` order.

```
sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['date'], reverse=True)[0]
```

sorts the list by the date (in ascending order - oldest to the latest)
If you add `reverse=True`, then it sorts in descending order (latest to the oldest). `[0]` returns the first element in the list which is the latest snapshot.

If you want the `snap_id` of the latest snapshot, just access that key.

```
sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['date'], reverse=True)[0]['snap_id']
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't print the latest snapshot `{'snap_id': 'snap-0faa111050c72', 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 19, 3, 0, 17, tzinfo=tzutc())}`, I think need to sort it by the date of the snapshot (in aws is column `Started` )

Comment: do you know maybe how do I access the result and get only the `snap_id` value ?

Comment: when I sort it by `date` (`print(sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['date'], reverse=True)[0])`) , it gave the latest snapshot , not sure I understand, the sort in reverse order sort automatically the snapshots dates ? my second q - how I can access the snap_id (take it out to another var) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_snapshots():
    list_of_snaps = []
    for snapshot in ec2client_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']:
    snapshot_volume = snapshot['VolumeId']
    mnt_vol = "vol-xxxxx"
    if mnt_vol == snapshot_volume:
        snapshot_date = snapshot['StartTime']
        snapshot_id = snapshot['SnapshotId']
        list_of_snaps.append({'date':snapshot['StartTime'], 'snap_id': snapshot['SnapshotId']})
        print(snapshot_id)
        print(snapshot_date)

    #sort snapshots order by date
    newlist = sorted(list_of_snaps, key=lambda k: k['date'], reverse= True)
    latest_snap_id = newlist[0]['snap_id']
    #The latest_snap_id provides the exact output snapshot ID
    print(latest_snap_id)
```

Comment: Give some explanation rather than just giving the code.

Answer (score 1):

The last line needs to be like this:

```
newlist = sorted(list_of_snaps, key=lambda k: k['snap_id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the snapshots to list, then sort the list based on date

```
def find_snapshots():
    list_of_snaps = []
    for snapshot in ec2client_describe_snapshots['Snapshots']:
    snapshot_volume = snapshot['VolumeId']
    mnt_vol = "vol-xxxxx"
    if mnt_vol == snapshot_volume:
        snapshot_date = snapshot['StartTime']
        snapshot_id = snapshot['SnapshotId']
        list_of_snaps.append({'date':snapshot['StartTime'], 'snap_id': snapshot['SnapshotId']})
        print(snapshot_id)
        print(snapshot_date)

    #sort snapshots order by date
    newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

**Hope it helps !!**

Comment: thanks, I got an error `NameError: name 'list_to_be_sorted' is not defined`, should be instead `list_of_snaps` ? if so, I got empty array, when I try to print `newlist`, any suggestion ? thanks